# How can an Android application find out that files have been modified from a PC?

Tags: android

My application is accessing files from a single special directory. I want the application to be notified when the user connects the device to a computer and modifies the files (adds, removes, renames etc.).
Per-file notifications are not necessary, the application just needs to know that it should rescan the directory.
An ideal solution would also work for an SD card.

The `FileObserver` doesn't work in this case (and the documentation indirectly says so).

I have tried using a `BroadcastReceiver` to watch for the `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` intent, with no luck.
Since I'm interested in audio files, I have also experimented with `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED` but this has proven unreliable: it works on an SGS3 but not on a Nexus 7 with Android 5.1. I assume the media scanner is not guaranteed to run on all devices.

I could try using a combination of different methods (watching for all of the intents that come to mind like the above and maybe others lie `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED`) but if possible, I'd like to use a more reliable approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a good solution but I think I have found a satisfactory one.

I have switched from watching the `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED` to using a `ContentObserver`. The `ContentObserver.onChange` method is called multiple times so I use a timer to delay the actual file scan on each call to `onChange`.

```java
public class MediaStoreUpdateObserver extends ContentObserver {

    private static final int RESCAN_DELAY_MS = 15000;

    private final Handler mainThreadHandler;

    public MediaStoreUpdateObserver(Handler mainThreadHandler) {
        super(mainThreadHandler);
        this.mainThreadHandler = mainThreadHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        mainThreadHandler.removeCallbacks(delayedRescanTask);
        mainThreadHandler.postDelayed(delayedRescanTask, RESCAN_DELAY_MS);
    }

    private final Runnable delayedRescanTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Start file rescan.
        }
    };
}
```

Again, this is a hack, but it does the job.